# Fab button with custom image

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I would like to add my custom icon to the fab button,
I specified it like

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_custom" />
```

its showing the icon but not completely filling fab, leaving some margin around.

I want my icon to completely occupy the fab size and width (my icon is circular)

Comment: What is the icon size in dp?

Comment: I have icon in all res `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, `xxxhdpi`

Comment: Did you try with larger size icon?

Comment: yes what ever is the icon size, its just appearing at the center with margin around

Comment: You want the icon inside fab to increase size or reduce the size of fab?
`app:fabSize="mini"` will make a mini fab.

Comment: I want don't want to change fab size, my icon inside fab is appearing smaller, I want it to occupy complete width and height

Answer (score 3):

Floating action button will automatically add padding to the icon. It won't allow image to occupy whole width/height which is against [guidelines](https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button).

For such create a custom circular `ImageButton` with a shadow/elevation.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix:
Use Relative Layout as the root layout. Instead of fab, use a normal image view or a  button and set the src to your custom icon and the position as desired. Let's say you have a ScrollView with id "sv" over which you want to float the button. Just use android:layout_above="@id/sv" where sv is  your ScrollView.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
android:layout_width="56dp"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:layout_above="@id/sv"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"

android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="edit"
android:padding="0dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/ic_pen" />
```